# Split string into array with pattern

Tags: php, apache-flex

I send from flex an array to my php script.
String to split is like [F1, 3, true][Urg, 4, false]
I'd to use those information to update record into mySql database.

For example [F1, 3, true] is a record like this [Name, Id, Visible].

But I don't how to split to use information.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Why don't you send json data, or some other serializable data format?

Answer (score 0):

If you really insist on that format you could try preg_match.

```
$string = '[F1, 3, true][Urg, 4, false][asd,      1337, TrUe]';
preg_match_all('/\[(\w+),\s*?(\d+),\s*?(true|false)\]/i', $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

With this you will get an two-dimensional array, each element in the array is an array. The first element in each array is the matches data row, the following elements are the parsed data.
The elements can be separated by as many whitespace characters as you want, the case of the boolean value does not matter.

Comment: I try to use your explain, but $matches is empty. I test with $arrayTest = $matches[0][0] . ", " . $matches[0][1];
And the result is only comma. Do you know why?

Comment: Your data does not arrive in the format you specified. Have a look at http://codepad.viper-7.com/rE2CD2 to see a working example.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the brackets:

```
$txt = substr($txt, 1, -1);
```

And explode:

```
$array = explode(',', $txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope there are no commas or square brackets in your data strings - that could make this impossible!  But assuming there are none of those:

```
preg_match_all('/\[([^\]]*)\]/', $text, $matches);
return array_map(function($match) {
    return array_map('trim', explode(',', $match));
}, $matches[1]);
```

(That uses a closure, which is only supported in PHP 5.3 and later; if you are on an older version, you can change it to a foreach loop pretty easily.)

Comment: With this you have the result in an array as the first element of an single element array.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't quite using `preg_match_all` properly.  It's fixed now.

Comment: @clentfort: The result should be a two-dimensional array.  If you only provide one row of data, then yes, you will get an array containing one array.

Comment: I missunderstood his question. I thought he is only providing one row each time.

Comment: You also should change the delimiter for the explode function or he will have not trimmed data.

Comment: If he needs trimmed data, why not `trim()` it?  I'm hesitant to rely on the format in the OP matching the actual format whitespace-for-whitespace.  Hmm, but I'll edit trimming into my answer.